# My SQL Query is very slow with 50K+ records

Tags: mysql, performance, sqlperformance

I have a table called links in which I am having 50000 + records where three of the fields are having indexes in the order `link_id` ,`org_id` ,`data_id`.

Problem here is when I am using group by sql query it is taking more time to load.

The Query is like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT `links`.* 
FROM `links` 
WHERE `links`.`org_id` = 2 AND (link !="") 
GROUP BY link
```

The table is having nearly 20+ columns

Is there any solution to speed up the query to access faster.

Comment: Add `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` to see what's happening and why it's slow.

Answer (score 3):

Build an index on `(org_id, link)`

`org_id` to optimize your `WHERE` clause, and `link` for your `group by` (and also part of `where`).

By having the LINK_ID in the first position is probably what is holding your query back.

```
create index LinksByOrgAndLink on Links ( Org_ID, Link );
```

[MySQL Create Index syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Sorry I have mistaken it is not link_id . It is the field link .

Comment: And Can you tell me how to add the "Build an index on (org_id, link)"

Comment: Do you mean the multiple column indexes ?

Comment: Sorry, YES... one index and it is indexed on BOTH columns, not two individual indexes one column each.

Comment: @RANZIT----user1242400, yes if you don't need it... but you can have many indexes on a table based on whatever helps optimize respective queries that you may run.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your DISTINCT.* 
the GROUP BY is already doing the work of `DISTINCT` , so are doing distinct two times , one of `SELECT DISTINCT`  and other for `GROUP BY`

try this

```
    SELECT  * 
    FROM `links` 
    WHERE org_id` = 2 AND (link !="") 
    GROUP BY link
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding a index to your 'link' column would improve the result.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Only select the columns that you need.

Why is there a distinct for `links`.*? 
Do you have some rows exactly doubled in your table?

On the other hand, changing the value "" to NULL could be improve your select statement, but iam not sure about this.